# Export to Unity results in loss of animation information

Tags: animation, armature, export, unity, .fbx

**Introduction**

When exporting armatures with animations to Unity, I've had a problem, where animations from Blender behave differently in Unity. Some bones either lose their information completely or get it distorted.
Everything in the Unity rigging settings looks fine, all bones are detected etc.

I found the link below on a Unity forum question, that dealt with the usual "-90X degree rotation issue". However it turns out, that export method #3 from the video link (02:25 - 03:25) also solves my issue, **if I also** include the mesh in the export.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpH5ZfonExo

**How I did it before**

With a rigged and animated character in Blender, I kept the Blender rotations, exported as FBX to open in a new Blender file, where I rotate the armature to -90X degree rotation, apply rotation, then exported as FBX to Unity (All Local Scale), without the mesh. This gave me a correctly rotated animation in Unity, but resulted in missing bone information.

**How I do it now**

With a rigged and animated character in Blender, I rotate the armature to -90X degree rotation (mesh is a child of armature), apply rotation, then rotate 90 degrees back, but only apply that rotation on the mesh objects. Then export as FBX to Unity (FBX Units Scale), **with the mesh**. This gives me a correctly rotated animation and no missing bone information.

**Question**

**Q)** How do I export animations without loss of information, without having to export the mesh?

*I've been looking in both Unity and Blender forums for an answer, with no luck.*

Comment: Do you use constraints?

Comment: I don't. The armature is a slightly modified metarig - no constraints.